# When is a reference asked to submit a recommendation letter during postdoc hiring?

Tags: postdocs, recommendation-letter, job-search, interview, norway

I have applied to a postdoc position at NTNU in Norway. I was invited to an interview and I think it went okay, they indicated that a decision would be reached within 1 week due to the urgency of this position. Now the time frame has passed and I did not hear back so I assumed my application was not successful. However  during the weekend my advisor sent me an email about just sending out a strong recommendation letter to the hiring committee. I know that my supervisor is quite busy in addition to not being in the best health conditions. So I am thinking may be the recommendation letters were asked some time ago, EVEN before my interview, but it was down of my supervisor priority list :)

My questions are:

1- does the hiring committee ask for recommendation letters from the references I provided before or after an interview, specifically in case of NTNU?

2- And generally, would my references be contacted for every position I apply for during early hiring stages (i.e., before even an interview) whether that be postdocs in US or EU?

Comment: Postdoc hiring practices in Europe (at least the countries I'm familiar with) are in the hands of the hiring PI, and hence, completely depend on individual factors. The PI decides when and if they want to contact references - from my own experiences, I know that sometimes (some of) the references are never contacted.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the job announcement, presumably at jobbnorge.no, and see what kinds of documents it lists over there. If they do not ask for letters of recommendation at that stage, then they do not; they might or might not use such at a later stage, but that is not really your problem.

The process I had to go through to secure a postdoc position at NTNU was not fast. I recommend patience, and if in doubt, a polite question to your potential future supervisor.